# Is it possible to pass components as props, or Images as props

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to figure out is it possible to pass down a component as a prop.
So for this button component i want to make it so i could pass down images into the span, where i currently have ArrowRight.

````
   
 export default function Button({ text }) {
    const [arrowColor, setArrowColor] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div>
            <button
                className={styles.button}
                onMouseEnter={() => setArrowColor(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setArrowColor(false)}
            >
                {text}
                <span className={styles.rightArrow}>
                    <ArrowRight fill={`${arrowColor ? "white" : "black" }`} />
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}```
````

Comment: you can paas image url as a prop, and then use that URL inside your button component

Comment: you can paas image url as a prop, and then use that URL inside your button component